# Length of a vector defined from the length of other vectors

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

The problem in question is:

if $\|u\|=3$, $\|u+v\|=4$ & $\|u-v\|=6$, what is $\|v\|$?

I'm currently in my first course of linear algebra and I'm stuck on this question. I've tried applying a mix of multiple rules to it, such as the Cauchy-Schwars inequality, inner products, the Pythagorean theorem and perpendicular projection but to no avail. Please help, I'm going mad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
16=\|u+v\|^2=\langle u+v,u+v\rangle =\langle u,u\rangle +2\langle u,v\rangle +\langle v,v\rangle =\|u\|^2+2\langle u,v\rangle +\|v\|^2
$$

$$
36=\|u-v\|^2=\langle u-v,u-v\rangle =\langle u,u\rangle -2\langle u,v\rangle +\langle v,v\rangle =\|u\|^2-2\langle u,v\rangle +\|v\|^2
$$

$$52=36+16=\|u-v\|^2+\|u+v\|^2=2\|u\|^2+2\|v\|^2=2\cdot 9+2\|v\|^2
$$
Finally,
$$\|v\|=\sqrt{\frac{52-18}2}=\sqrt{17}
$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $52=36+16=||u-v||^2+||u+v||^2$? You are adding?

Comment: yup, fixed,  thanks!

Comment: I went through the same steps of my proof, except I made the mistake to subtract instead of add :)

Comment: guess why I had the problem with the sign^)

Comment: cheers guys, this clears up a lot :)